# The "Ask Question" button brings up the last question I asked for edit

Tags: support, asking-questions

How can I ask a new question on Stack Overflow? The "Ask Question" button brings me back to a [MVC 3 Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7408794/), which I asked yesterday. I've received two answers on the earlier question; I tried adding an answer, accepting one of the proposed answers (even though it didn't really answer my question). I've tried closing my browser, etc.

Is there a limit to 1 question per week or something along those lines?
I've read similar questions to this, but they either don't provide answers or a solution. I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you use a browser?

Comment: Stack Overflow saves a draft when you are typing, but that should be cleared when you actually post the question. You should be able to delete the old text and type in some new.

Comment: I submitted the question yesterday. I've received two answers as well as answered it myself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408794/mvc-3-image-upload/7408840#7408840

Comment: OK, just restarted my computer and it's still doing it. Been using FireFox, tried opening in IE. Got prompted to log in when I clicked the Ask Question button. After logging in, it took me to my Question from yesterday. What's going on?

Comment: It's saved on the server. Just erase it all and start your new question—it's not going to overwrite your old question (it's not an edit form).

Comment: What do you mean by "taking you to your question from yesterday"?  As in, you clicked on the "Ask Question" link but you were taken to your previously asked question?  Or you clicked on the "Ask Question" link and you saw the contents of your previously asked question filled in?

Comment: I was taken to my previously asked question as if I had clicked on a link for that question and then clicked the edit link once there. It's how I got to my question and edited it. Once I submitted it, problem solved.

Comment: fyi I am also having this problem. I normally use Ffx, so I tried login to Safari, and it still happened (so it's not a cache/cookie issue).

Comment: I am also getting this. Could it be because the question is silently being ignored by SO as part of a passive-aggressive spam control measure? @waiwai933, are you sure about deleting it?

Comment: It's happened to me a few times.  My original solution of Submitting it again didn't work.  It told me I was trying to submit a duplicate question.  So, I simply deleted all the text in the question header and detail areas and entered my new question. Definitely a problem they aren't concerned with.

Comment: @highBandWidth 100% sure. Even if I were wrong, SE stores all previous revisions of a question.

Comment: I also have this issue today, and I also posted a question for the tag mvc.

Comment: After entering some new text and different tags I can post again.

Comment: I've had ti happen a few times as well. Not sure what it is that causes it.  Hadn't thought about the Tag.

Comment: I have the same issue, everyone seems sure about just emptying the form and asking posting the next question, but how comes no one has posted the solution as an answer? I'd do it myself, but I don't want to be rude and steal someone else's credit... looking at you @waiwai933, it's your rep to take :)